# Dynamically creating an Interface with static method in Android using ByteBuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I have this code which works fine with byte buddy in normal Java but it does not work in Android.

```
Class c = new ByteBuddy().makeInterface().name("TestInterface")
                    .defineMethod("test",String.class, Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC)
                    .intercept(FixedValue.value("Hello")).make()
                    .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                            new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Wrapping(context.getCacheDir())).getLoaded();
            Object o = c.getMethod("test").invoke(c);
```

After running this in Android I get the error `Cannot define non-virtual method test for a pre-java 8 interface type`.

I actually checked and from Android version 24 and later Interfaces with static methods is supported but I think the issue is that when you query Android for 'java.version' property it returns 0 which makes byte-buddy think we are an older version of JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte Buddy validates against the Java version that is inferred from the platform context and on Android, this is indeed too strict. You can disable validation by setting:

```
new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED)
```